# chrome extension - opening multiple tabs won't open all tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I created an extension, that opens all URL's entered in textarea in popup window. With the latest chrome versions, it stopped working correctly - sometimes it opens all entered tabs, but sometimes only some of them.

I have find some info, that the script needs to move to background.js and this should solve this issue, but I am not sure how to do it. Can you please help me?

#### manifest.js

```
{"name": "URL Opener",
"description": "",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": { "128": "url_128x128.png" },
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "background"],
"browser_action": {
"default_title": "URL Opener+",
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"],"persistent": false
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### popup.html

here I have only that textarea and clicking button

#### popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {var divs1 = document.getElementById("button");divs1.addEventListener('click', URLopener);});

function URLopener () {var txt = document.getElementById("textfield").value; 
for(i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){chrome.tabs.create({url: txt[i]});}
```

}

Until now it worked fine, but now it won't always open all tabs...

I tried to move the function URLopener () to the background.js, but don't know how exactly call it from popup.js, or what else to do...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

Here's one (**message passing**) :

In **popup.js** send **background.js** a message with some data structure of your sites.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    urls: ['http://example.url.whatever.com',
           'http://another.example.of.url.com']
});
```

Then, in **background.js** handle the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.urls) {
            //request.urls is the array of urls from popup.js
        }
    }
);
```

Please read further documentation here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will study this! 

However, for now I solved the issue via "active":false - I just included this here 

    chrome.tabs.create({"active":false, url: txt[i]});

and it works perfectly, so I don't need to use background. It causes not to focus on opening tabs, so it will open all tabs everytime.